# Transparent Navigation bar becomes solid colour when scrolling to bottom

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have a tableview controller which has an embedded navigation bar. I managed to make my nav bar transparent. Now I am trying to achieve a solid color nav bar when I scroll towards the bottom of the table view. I am relatively new to iOS development. So please answer accordingly. I have no idea about scroll views either. I am not sure if I need to add a scroll view or not. If I do, where do I add it? Above the tableview or below it?

Here are a few images of what I want to achieve:

Image 1: Transparent nav bar, but bar button items are visible
[image]
Image 2: Transparent nav bar becoming white, bar button items' color changing from white to red
[image]
Image 3: This is the final image, where nav bar becomes white and bar button items become red.
[image]

If we scroll back up to the top, everything goes back to being the way it was at the start.

Comment: did you fixed this issue or you added custom buttons?